# How to add a custom sort function to the jquery grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a table built using JQuery Grid containing 3 columns (name, date, value). 'date' and 'value' columns can have null or 'NA' values. So when I use the below code as part of jqGrid function it works for the 'name' but not for 'date' and 'value' :

```
    colModel: [
                {name: "name", sortable: true},
                {name: "date", sortable: true},
                {name: "value", sortable: true}
            ],
```

How can I get the sorting worked for date and value columns. How should I add the custom sorting to this ?

Comment: What is the error when you try to sort with value or date?

Comment: @Periklis I found the issue. But I also found that it is hitting the backend for each sorting (whenever the user clicks on the column header). Is there any better way to do that sorting in jquery grid?

Comment: @Nisman: Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=3.7)? The possibilities of custom sorting depend on the information. Moreover if you really use remote datatype (`"json"` or `"xml"`) and no `loadonce: true` then *the server* is responsible for sorting. If you sort the data *on the client side* then the format of input data (like dates) is required to know. Please append your question with the above information.

Comment: @Oleg I am using jqGrid  4.4.4 , remote datatype is json and loadonce is set to false. This is a old code in my project and I have to add those two sortable columns to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `datatype: "json"` and `loadonce: false` then sorting do **only your server**. No client side feature (jqGrid) can help you to implement custom sorting. You have to implement custom sorting in your **server side code**. For example, if the user click on the header of `"date"` column then jqGrid just sends the Ajax requestto the server with parameters `sidx=date` and `sord=asc` (or `sidx=date` and `sord=desc`). The server have to return correctly sorted JSON data and jqGrid displays the data in the order returned by the server.

Thus you have to implement the custom sorting in your server side code.

Answer (score 0):

The colModel name should be the same as in your table.

Comment: Now I found out how it is working. Actually there are two problems: first I don't want to hit the backend for sorting. second the date and value columns values coming from different table. They are based on some calculations.